# Creating a music player with javafx and scene builder

Tags: java, media-player, media, fxml

I'm trying to create my own version of iTunes. I am trying to create a music player and this is my method:

```
public void audioPlayerButtons(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if (actionEvent.getSource() == playbtn) {

        String bip = "/Users/april121/Work/MyMusic!/src/sample/Songs/01 Clarity.m4a";
        Media hit = new Media(bip);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
        MediaPlayer.play();

    }

   else (actionEvent.getSource()== pausebtn){
           MediaPlayer.pause();
   }

   else (actionEvent.getSource()==forwardbtn){
       MediaPlayer.seek(MediaPlayer.getStartTime());
       MediaPlayer.stop();
   }

   else (actionEvent.getSource()==backwardbtn){
//to be finished
    }
```

But I have tried for hours now - be it through importing libraries from Maven or hard coding and it's not working.

I'd like it show what's playing and have basic functions ie. play, pause, rewind and forward and have a progress bar.

this is the error it is showing:

```
non-static method can't be accessed in static context. And the part that is causing the error is the ".stop()" or ".play()" bits
```

but I don't understand why - because my method is non-static anyways

[image]

Comment: We can't do that for you. Instead, you give use the error messages you get and the code generating that error, and then we can help. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: could you help me understand why functions like:MediaPlayer.stop() arent working

Comment: You have to be more specific. What do you mean when you say it isn't working?

Comment: it's throwing an error saying: non-static methods can't be accessed from a static context. But my method is non-static for this program

Comment: You didn't get me right: what I meant is "edit your question", its too broad and could be closed. And I have absolutely no idea of what your problem is, I just reviewed your question.

Comment: sorry if it sounds silly - i'm just a beginner!

Comment: @KevinWorkman, Hey, I have edited the question, could you help me out? Also, would you have suggestions as to how to build the mp3 player using a library? thanks a ton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at these lines:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
MediaPlayer.play();
```

That second line is calling a static `play()` function, which doesn't work. The `play()` function is non-static. That's why you're getting the error you're getting.

You probably mean this instead:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

If you have other questions, post them as separate questions and try to be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try naming it something else ie.

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer (hit);
mp.play();
```

That way you won't have a confusion!